# Script error: Object doesn't support property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I working on a Bug for more than 2 hours and it is driving me nuts.  I am getting script error

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'corner'**

when I try to navigate to a page. I tried checking the jquery version and stuff but cannot get over the error. any ideas on what I am missing?

thanks

Comment: `corner`? I think you really ought to post some code to get help.

Comment: that's the kind of error you get when something is undefined.

Comment: You are missing showing us some code to help you with :)

Comment: @Mark I am sorry.. actually I fixed the bug. It was with the conflict in imports. I wanted to put it as a answer as a future reference for a novice like me but since my score is less than 100 SOF is not allowing me to answer my own question for 100 hours.. thanks

Comment: HINT: a more complete personal profile would do you well in assisting you with that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the object is null. It might be that the value is either missing.look at your method signature and also the imports